# Resetting EF Code-First Migration State

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 5. We are looking to convert our project to use code-first migrations.

Originally in our DBContext file we had an IDataBaseInitializer implementation that creates the DB if it doesn't exist (using context.Database.Create).

I wanted to test out the migration concept so I originally ran the commands:

Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyProjectName
(This successfully created a Migrations folder with a Configuration.cs file)

Add-Migration Initial -ProjectName MyProjectName
(This successfully created a script file which matched my model classes)

At this point I wanted to try testing upgrade scenario so I created a tmp field on my model and reran the Add-Migration command which seemed to work as expected.

However at this point I wanted to reset my state. I've reverted all my changes in VS, removed the files from the Migrations folder from disk, tried removing the __MigrationsHistory table from my DB (and also completely deleting the DB). No matter what I do I can't get a new Add-Migration to create a script that includes my initial state. It always appears as this... this is my test value that I created originally.

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
       DropColumn("dbo.EventTrackingRecords", "TestValue");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.EventTrackingRecords", "TestValue", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

I don't understand where it's keeping this initial information. The only other thing that I found interesting is that if I run my program after deleting the DB, it recreates my DB as I would expect based on the model, but it also creates a __MigrationHistory table! I don't understand how the context.Database.Create() command is doing this.

Comment: I would assume that what is in the `Initial` class that you posted IS the history.  Have you tried removing `DropColumn` and `AddColumn` from there and rerunning your test?

Comment: I don't have my original Initial class that I created which included all my models. I had reverted everything and assumed I could just redo it. I tried removing the DropColumn and AddColumn. It just creates the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

EF creates the __MigrationHistory table to keep your DB up to date, and warn you if it's not.

When you edit something in your models, and run the add-migration, you have to run update-database to be able to create a new migration. EF won't allow you to have pending migrations while creating new ones.

So, if you add a property to one of your models, and then create a migration, you have to update the database before creating a new migration where you delete the property.

Hope this helps.